# Still receiving Timeout connects using JS DAX client, classified as an error but no impact

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-dax

We use the JS amaxon-dax-client (1.2.3) and we receive a bunch of

```
ERROR   Failed to pull from <cluster>.cache.amazonaws.com (-.-.-.-): TimeoutError: Connection timeout after 10000ms
    at SocketTubePool.alloc (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/amazon-dax-client/src/Tube.js:227:64)
    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/amazon-dax-client/generated-src/Operations.js:215:30
```

My understanding is this is a warning, not an error? We don't see any adverse effects (at least not noticeable) and the functions can access DAX just fine, but it pollutes our logs.

If the DAX endpoint isn't properly configured, the DB operations fail which isn't what we're seeing here.