# Intermittent behaviour of a lambda connecting to DAX

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am trying to connect a lambda to DAX (the DynamoDB in-memory cache). I am setting it up via CDK. After much effort I got it working today, and then it stopped working a couple of hours afterwards.

All it does is write a record to DynamoDB or DAX depending on the mode. It can write to DynamoDB reliably, but I seem to be making a fundamental error with DAX, and there seems to be little rhyme or reason why it does or doesn't work.

Firstly, here is a cut down version of the lambda:

```
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';
import AmazonDaxClient from 'amazon-dax-client';

function instantiateDrivers(daxClusterEndpoint: string) {
    const options = {
        endpoint: 'http://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    };

    // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.concepts.cluster.html
    if (daxClusterEndpoint && daxClusterEndpoint.length > 0) {
        console.log(`Using DAX cluster: ${daxClusterEndpoint}`);
        const dax = new AmazonDaxClient({
            endpoints: [`daxs://${daxClusterEndpoint}`],
            region: 'eu-west-1',
            maxRetries: 1,
        });
        // @ts-ignore
        options.service = dax;
    }

    const dynamoDbServiceClient = new DynamoDB(options);
    console.log(`Instantiated DynamoDB`);
    const dynamoDbDocumentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient(options);
    console.log(`Instantiated DocumentClient`);

    return { dynamoDbServiceClient, dynamoDbDocumentClient };
}

async function writeRecord(daxClusterEndpoint: string, voucherTableName: string, record: any) {
    // Create the drivers
    let { dynamoDbDocumentClient } = instantiateDrivers(daxClusterEndpoint);

    console.log(`Instantiated drivers OK`);

    // Do the write
    await dynamoDbDocumentClient.
    put({ TableName: voucherTableName, Item: record}).
    promise();
}

function validateArguments(event: any) {
    const { VOUCHER_TABLE_NAME, DAX_CLUSTER_ENDPOINT } = event;

    if (!VOUCHER_TABLE_NAME) {
        throw new Error(`A VOUCHER_TABLE_NAME must be supplied`);
    }

    return {
        voucherTableName: VOUCHER_TABLE_NAME,
        daxClusterEndpoint: DAX_CLUSTER_ENDPOINT,
    };
}

export const handler =  async (event: any, context: any) => {
    console.log("Received lambda call: " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    // Try to get args
    const { voucherTableName, daxClusterEndpoint } = validateArguments(event);

    // This is a record we want to write
    await writeRecord(
        daxClusterEndpoint,
        voucherTableName,
        // Note the object is in v2 format, not v1 (with the 'S' 'M' and 'BOOL' type keys)
        {
            "code": "TEST-VOUCHER-1234",
            "siteId": "3",
            "endDate": "2022-08-31T13:39:56.000Z",
            "name": "permanent",
            "startDate": "2022-07-20T13:39:56.000Z",
            "type": "XPercentOffProductPromotion",
            "used": false,
        }
    );

    return context.logStreamName;
};
```

Next, here is the CDK:

```
import {CfnOutput, Stack, StackProps, Duration} from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as path from "path";
import {NodejsFunction} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs";
import {Runtime} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import {PolicyStatement, Role, ServicePrincipal, Effect} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam"
import {Vpc, SecurityGroup, SubnetType} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";

export class SupportScriptStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const importedVpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'imported-vpc', { vpcName: `${process.env.STAGE}-eu-west-1`})

    const voucherStatement = new PolicyStatement({
      resources: [
        'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:*:table/voucher-promotion-*',
        'arn:aws:dax:eu-west-1:*:cache/dax-cluster-preprod'
      ],
      actions: [
        "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
        "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
        "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:Scan",
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
        "dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive",
        "dynamodb:ListTables",
        "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
        "dax:BatchGetItem",
        "dax:BatchWriteItem",
        "dax:PutItem",
        "dax:DescribeTable",
        "dax:DeleteItem",
        "dax:GetItem",
        "dax:Scan",
        "dax:Query",
        "dax:UpdateItem",
        "dax:DescribeTimeToLive",
        "dax:ListTables",
        "dax:DescribeLimits"
      ]
    });

    const securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(
      this,
      "LambdaSecurityGroup",
      {
        vpc: importedVpc,
        description: "Demo API Security Group",
        allowAllOutbound: true,
      }
    );

    const role = new Role(this, "DemoApiLambdaRole", {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
    });
    role.addToPolicy(
      new PolicyStatement({
        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          // VPC
          "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
          "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:DescribeInstances",
          "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
          // DAX
          "dax:*",
          // Need Dynamo as well
          "dynamo:*",
        ],
        resources: ["*"],
      })
    );

    const voucherCodeFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, `VC-Create`, {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      functionName: `voucher-code-importer`,
      timeout: Duration.minutes(3), // Long timeout for now during debug phase
      memorySize: 512,
      bundling: {
        minify: true,
      },
      handler: "handler",
      entry: path.join(__dirname, `../src/create-voucher/handler.ts`),
      vpc: importedVpc,
      // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72159511
      securityGroups: [securityGroup],
      role
    });

    voucherCodeFunction.addToRolePolicy(voucherStatement);

    new CfnOutput(this, 'voucher-code-function-arn', {value: voucherCodeFunction.functionArn})
  }
}
```

The CDK has been through a frustrating set of confusing iterations - it works in one format, I tidy it up or tighten some permissions, it stops working, I revert to the old working version, and now that has stopped working too.

I am certain this worked for a period without the `const voucherStatement = new PolicyStatement` section - I restored that in case it was the cause of the fresh set of failures. I am pretty sure this duplicates permissions the lambda has separately.

One of the things that may have helped was synchronizing the lambda's subnets with the ones for the lambda. In this project, a colleague has set up a statement of the available subnets, in a file called `cdk.context.json`.

I believe I have synced this correctly, but I am pretty much clutching at straws at this point. Slightly redacted, but it should be clear enough:

```
{
  "vpc-provider:account=9015xxxxxxxx:filter.tag:Name=preprod-eu-west-1:region=eu-west-1:returnAsymmetricSubnets=true": {
    "vpcId": "vpc-0d891xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "vpcCidrBlock": "172.35.0.0/16",
    "availabilityZones": [],
    "subnetGroups": [
      {
        "name": "Private",
        "type": "Private",
        "subnets": [
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0ad04xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.a.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1b",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-0fee4xxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-08598xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.z.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1c",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-0f477xxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Public",
        "type": "Public",
        "subnets": [
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0fba3xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.y.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1b",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-02dfbxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "subnetId": "subnet-0a3b8xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidr": "172.35.x.0/22",
            "availabilityZone": "eu-west-1c",
            "routeTableId": "rtb-02dfbxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I write the record to Dynamo (by not supplying a `DAX_CLUSTER_ENDPOINT` key in the payload) then it is fine. But if I supply a value for this (`dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`) then it sometimes works for a couple of hours, sometimes does not.

I notice that in the errors the system is not able to resolve the `daxs://` address, but later on, gives the IP addresses it resolves to (and from which it "failed to pull"):

```
2022-08-03T12:01:58.698+01:00   START RequestId: 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 Version: $LATEST
    2022-08-03T12:01:58.700+01:00   2022-08-03T11:01:58.700Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 INFO Received lambda call: { "VOUCHER_TABLE_NAME": "voucher-promotion-preprod", "DAX_CLUSTER_ENDPOINT": "dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" }
    2022-08-03T12:01:58.701+01:00   2022-08-03T11:01:58.700Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 INFO Using DAX cluster: dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    2022-08-03T12:01:58.738+01:00   2022-08-03T11:01:58.738Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 INFO Instantiated DynamoDB
    2022-08-03T12:01:58.740+01:00   2022-08-03T11:01:58.740Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 INFO Instantiated DocumentClient
    2022-08-03T12:01:58.740+01:00   2022-08-03T11:01:58.740Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 INFO Instantiated drivers OK
    2022-08-03T12:02:28.754+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:28.754Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524538749, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:28.762+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:28.762Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524538761, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:32.734+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:32.734Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.222.11,172.35.111.222,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524542732, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:32.740+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:32.740Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.212,172.35.111.222,172.35.222.11): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:9) { time: 1659524542739, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:36.735+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:36.735Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:9) { time: 1659524546732, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:36.741+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:36.741Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524546740, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:40.736+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:40.735Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:9) { time: 1659524550732, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:40.740+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:40.740Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524550740, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:56.740+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:56.740Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524566738, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:56.743+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:56.743Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:9) { time: 1659524566743, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:58.756+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:58.756Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524568755, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:58.756+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:58.756Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR as [Error]: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 { time: 1659524578756, code: 'NoRouteException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:58.764+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:58.764Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524568763, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:02:58.764+01:00   2022-08-03T11:02:58.764Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR as [Error]: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 { time: 1659524578764, code: 'NoRouteException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:00.740+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:00.740Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524570738, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:02.743+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:02.743Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR caught exception during cluster refresh: as [Error]: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524582743, code: 'NoRouteException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:02.743+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:02.743Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Error: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    2022-08-03T12:03:02.744+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:02.744Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.222.11,172.35.111.222,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524572742, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:02.744+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:02.744Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR caught exception during cluster refresh: as [Error]: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 { time: 1659524582744, code: 'NoRouteException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:02.744+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:02.744Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Error: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645
    2022-08-03T12:03:04.741+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:04.741Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524574739, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:04.743+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:04.743Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524574742, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:06.743+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:06.743Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524576740, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:06.745+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:06.743Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR caught exception during cluster refresh: as [Error]: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524586743, code: 'NoRouteException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:06.745+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:06.745Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Error: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    2022-08-03T12:03:06.746+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:06.746Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212,172.35.111.222): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 { time: 1659524576742, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:06.746+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:06.746Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR caught exception during cluster refresh: as [Error]: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645 { time: 1659524586746, code: 'NoRouteException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:06.746+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:06.746Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Error: NoRouteException: not able to resolve address: [{"host":"dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com","port":9111,"scheme":"daxs"}] at yu._resolveAddr (/var/task/index.js:1:7887) at /var/task/index.js:1:8298 at /var/task/index.js:1:8645
    2022-08-03T12:03:08.746+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:08.746Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.222.11,172.35.111.212): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524578744, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:08.747+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:08.747Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Failed to pull from dax-cluster-preprod.xxxxxx.dax-clusters.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (172.35.111.222,172.35.111.212,172.35.222.11): so [Error]: ConnectionException: Connection timeout after 10000ms at Tu.alloc (/var/task/index.js:10:7418) at /var/task/index.js:66:89369 at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) { time: 1659524578745, code: 'ConnectionException', retryable: true, requestId: null, statusCode: -1, _tubeInvalid: false, waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false }
    2022-08-03T12:03:08.753+01:00   2022-08-03T11:03:08.752Z 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 ERROR Invoke Error {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"NoRouteException: No endpoints available","code":"NoRouteException","time":1659524588752,"retryable":true,"requestId":null,"statusCode":-1,"_tubeInvalid":false,"waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying":false,"stack":["Error: NoRouteException: No endpoints available"," at vu.leaderClient (/var/task/index.js:10:11634)"," at Object.getClient (/var/task/index.js:66:116939)"," at /var/task/index.js:66:120803"," at new Promise (<anonymous>)"," at G0.makeRequestWithRetries (/var/task/index.js:66:120779)"," at /var/task/index.js:66:121294"]}
    2022-08-03T12:03:08.757+01:00   END RequestId: 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000
    2022-08-03T12:03:08.757+01:00
REPORT RequestId: 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000  Duration: 70055.20 ms   Billed Duration: 70056 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 89 MB  Init Duration: 463.81 ms    
    REPORT RequestId: 08510000-0000-0000-0000-dc6255000000 Duration: 70055.20 ms Billed Duration: 70056 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 89 MB Init Duration: 463.81 ms
```

I have been around the houses on this, and there is nearly no relevant troubleshooting information available on DAX on the web. I am doing this work only because there is no DAX-aware record editor in the AWS console, and am worried that the system I am working on has effectively committed itself to a pre-release product.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: (I have trimmed some fairly identical lines out of the logs, as it exceeded the permitted length of a question).

Comment: If the same lambda sometimes works and sometimes doesn't it is a pretty big hint that something with the subnet routing is off. How many subnets do you have? Are they configured identically? Have you (at least for testing purposes) considered only deploying the lambda into one subnet and checking if that result in it consistently working or failing (both results tell you something)?

Comment: @luk2302: good thoughts, thanks. One thing I think I will try is to cut the context file down so that it includes only private subnets. I have a sneaking suspicion that DAX is attached only to the private ones, and I wonder if having two public, two private in this file is the cause of the unreliability.

Comment: Annoyingly I don't personally have permissions to run `aws dax describe-clusters`, though I wonder if my deployment pipeline does! I will update here.

Comment: OK, removing the public subnets from the context file has not worked either. I will see if I can confirm some information about the cluster first-hand (I have some screen-shots from a colleague, and I am certain they are right, but perhaps going through the motions with stimulate a new idea).

Comment: I should note I am nearly completely unfamiliar with subnets, and am only vaguely familiar with their purpose - I believe they are networking devices that carry traffic, but whether lambdas or databases attach to all of them or one of them randomly, I have no idea. I am doing what I can while operating outside of my comfort zone 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really would not have guessed the answer to this question. We have some other lambdas (created in Serverless not SDK) and it was pointed out to me that they have inbound rules on their security group. However I was creating my own, which had no inbound rules:

```
const securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(
  this,
  "LambdaSecurityGroup",
  {
    vpc: importedVpc,
    description: "Demo API Security Group",
    allowAllOutbound: true,
  }
);
```

Instead I should be reusing an existing one:

```
// This looks like the SG that web-based lambdas use to talk to DAX
const securityGroup = SecurityGroup.fromLookupByName(
  this,
  'VoucherImporterSecurityGroup',
  'default',
  importedVpc
);
```

I do not know why something needs to reach into the SG. The SG replicates my existing `allowAllOutbound: true` rule. I am however certain that I did not use this rule previously, and my lambda was able to connect to DAX several times over a few hours.

Time will tell if this is a reliable fix.

Answer (score 1):

If Lambda lives in the same VPC as DAX cluster:

```
daxSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
    lambdaSecurityGroup,
    Port.tcp(<DAX cluster port number>)
);
```

The DAX cluster port number is 8111 if unencrypted or 9111 if encrypted.

I guess [halfer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73229022/2914092) works because the VPC default security group already had the inbound rule accepting incoming traffics from resources within the same security group.